# DataFrame is highly fragmented

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code, but when I run it I receive the error:

PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead.  To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()

```
std_ltc = df["rolling_"+str(d)].std()
action_limit = [0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

df['num_cusum_sh_'+str(d)]=0
df['num_cusum_sl_'+str(d)]=0

for h in action_limit:
     #SH
     sh = "sh_dummy_ltc_"+str(d)+"_" + str(h)
     df[sh] = df["sh_ltc_"+str(d)]
     df[sh] = where(df["sh_ltc_"+str(d)] > (std_ltc * h),
                       int(1), df[sh].astype(int))
     df[sh] = where(df["sh_ltc_"+str(d)] < (std_ltc * h),
                       int(0), df[sh].astype(int))

     df['num_cusum_sh_'+str(d)]=df['num_cusum_sh_'+str(d)]+df[sh]

     # SL
     sl = "sl_dummy_ltc_"+str(d)+"_" + str(h)
     df[sl] = df["sl_ltc_"+str(d)]
     df[sl] = where(df["sl_ltc_"+str(d)] < (-std_ltc * h),
                       int(1), df[sl].astype(int))
     df[sl] = where(df["sl_ltc_"+str(d)] > (-std_ltc * h),
                       int(0), df[sl].astype(int))
        
     df['num_cusum_sl_'+str(d)]=df['num_cusum_sl_'+str(d)]+df[sl]
```

How do I avoid this annoing error?

Comment: that code looks like spaghetti! you should probably use `.apply(lambda x: 0 if som_condition else 0)` Clean up the code. Also using f-strings will help alot here. `f'sh_dummy_ltc_{d}_{h}'`

Comment: thanks for the comment but this does not resolve my problem

Comment: You are doing where twice per condition - or two passes. I am suggesting if you convert this to an apply you are reducing the processing of the dataframe by x 2. Now if you still have a problem after the above suggestions then please come back. But beyond re-writing it all myself and iterating that way, I think it is better for you to explore.

Comment: Things to do  1) add a column for std_dev  2) d[['a', 'b']].apply(lambda x: 1  if x[0] > x[1] * h  else 0)

I would also add in that you are looking at three conditions a < b and a > b and a == b. So you will need to use `.loc` to condition .

Comment: I am happy to help though.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that you need to use apply(lambda x: … , axis=1) when using multiple columns in an apply.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Really helpful. I guess that my issue is not on the part that you describe, but is more on the creation of the columns in the df in this part here:                                                                                                             sh = "sh_dummy_ltc_"+str(d)+"_" + str(h)
df[sh] = df["sh_ltc_"+str(d)]            I should find a way to create 'n' lists and then concatenate them in a df

Comment: I have updated - I don't believe you need so many temp cols. So please review and check with your dataset. If I have time I will create a minimal test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comments above

- issue with creating multiple columns

I don't believe you need to create so many new temp columns - instead you can just update based on the data, and have a function which accepts a parameter `h`.

```py
action_limit = [0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

num_cumsum_sl_col = f'num_cusum_sl_{d}'
num_cumsum_sh_col = f'num_cusum_sh_{d}'

df[num_cumsum_sh_col]=0
df[num_cumsum_sl_col]=0
df["std_ltc"] = df[f"rolling_{d}"].std()

def check_condition(x, h):
    ltc_sh_or_sl, std_ltc = x
    if std_ltc * h < ltc_sh_or_sl:
        res = 1
    elif std_ltc * h > ltc_sh_or_sl:
        res = 0
    else:
        # do we want this condition
        res = ltc_sh_or_sl  # is this an int?
    return res

for h in action_limit:
     #SH
     sh = f"sh_dummy_ltc_{d}_{h}"
     sl = f"sl_dummy_ltc_{d}_{h}"
     df[sh] = df[[f"sh_ltc_{d}", 'std_ltc']].apply(lambda x: check_condition(x, h), axis=1)
     df[sl] = df[[f"sl_ltc_{d}", 'std_ltc']].apply(lambda x: check_condition(x, h), axis=1)
     
     df[num_cumsum_sh_col] = df[num_cumsum_sh_col] + df[sh]
     df[num_cumsum_sl_col] = df[num_cumsum_sl_col] + df[sh]
```

Comment: This looks very elegant! Thanks! But actually in my final df I cannot find the column "sh_dummy_ltc_{d}_{h}" cause in the code above the variable sh is not assigned anywhere

Comment: Basically in this df they are missing all the dummies with the different h

Comment: I added the dummies in :) - I was not sure if it was necessary. But this new update should give you that now.